# How to setup Android NDK development environment on Windows 7?

Tags: android-ndk, gnu-make

I want to work on Android NDK, so I have to setup development environment.

I am using Windows 7 witch have some prerequisites (Requirements).

1. Cygwin 1.7 // that I had installed.
2. Cupcake (1.5) // Where can I download this?
3. GNU Make 3.81 // Where can i download this? and what is it's size?

> The Android NDK can only be used to target system images using
>       the Cupcake (1.5) or later releases of the platform.
>
> This is due to subtle toolchain and ABI related changed that make
>       it incompatible with 1.0 and 1.1 system images.

The NDK requires GNU Make 3.81 or later being available on your development
system. Earlier versions of GNU Make might work but have not been tested.

Answer (score 1):

You can install GNU Make package from Cygwin package manager:

[image: installing GNU Make 3.81]

I'm not sure about Cupcake, but it seems to be a version of Android. Probably it can be installed using ADT from Eclipse. (Please, fix me if I'm wrong.)